# p.adjust with n < than number of tests

Tags: r, bioconductor, p-value, genome

I would like to apply the `p.adjust` function in R where `n` is < number of p-values. The real number of independent tests is lower than the number of p-values as it cames from genomic data with Linkage Desequilibrium Desequilibrium (effective number of independent tests, Meff).

However, the `p.adjust` function do not allows it: `number of comparisons, must be at least length(p)`.

Someone knows how to change this default in function or other generic function to accomplish similar work? Thank you!

Followed Steps:

1 - 3242 tested markers = 3242 p-values

2 - Inferred Meff is:  1096 (http://simplem.sourceforge.net/ procedure)

Now I need to estimate the corrected treshould or corrected p-values based on Meff.

I am not sure which multiple test correction strategy fits better or how to apply it in my data.

Comment: I suggest you might receive better results asking at stats.stackexchange.com, as this is a methodology question?

Comment: If you have $M_effective$, why don't you just multiply $P$ by that value?

Comment: Šidák correction gives αp = 1−(1−αe)1/M and Bonferroni correction gives αp = αe/M. Where M need to be replaced by the effective number of independent tests, Meff, value. Why must I multiply?

Comment: Many people have been unimpressed with the reproducibility of the genomics stats predictions so even though I offer a coding strategy, I also suggest appropriate skepticism about  assumptions that would further improve the chances of finding "significant results".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code:

```
  p.adjust # typed at command line prints out the code
  # copy the body of the function
```

... is really very simple and all R. Just redefine a function that comments out that `stopifnot()` line:

```
my.p.adj <- function (p, method = p.adjust.methods, n = length(p)) 
 # paste the body and edit this:
....
p <- p[nna]
lp <- length(p)
# stopifnot(n >= lp)
if (n <= 1) 
....  # hit enter
```

Answer (score 1):

When using a smaller n in this way you may end up with p-values that are smaller than their unadjusted counterpart. To avoid this I suggest you can add an additional check to force the new p-values to be minimum the unadjusted p, just before the return of p0:

```
p0 <- ifelse(p0 < p, p, p0)
```